# Sending mail using java with attachment file working with Glassfish server but not with tomcat. What Should I do?

Tags: java, email, tomcat, glassfish

This Error is Showing, What Should I do to Remove it?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.SendFailedException: Sending failed;
nested exception is:
class javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response;
nested exception is:
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?

t javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:475)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:625)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:498)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:796)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1372)
at
```

org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at

Comment: Please, show you code.

Comment: Actually I was able to resolve the error myself. All I had to do was replace the java.mail jar while using GlassFish server with javax.mail jar when using Tomcat server and my code worked just fine. Thanks for the response though.

Answer (score 1):

Check the port number you're using in the URL.

The error message is showing that you're using HTTPS to connect to a port that is using plaintext.

Try 443 or 8443 for Tomcat.

Comment: The Error wasn't about the port number.